# How can I build a `Vec<i32>` from an `Iterator<Item=&i32>`?

Tags: rust, reference, iterator, ownership

I encountered an error when trying to use a function `get_even_numbers()` to borrow a vec `v` by passing it in by reference `&v` instead of by value `v`.

```
fn get_even_numbers(v: &Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    v.iter().filter(|x| x % 2 == 0).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<i32> = (0..10).collect();
    let even: Vec<i32> = get_even_numbers(&v);
    println!("Even numbers: {:?}", even);
}
```

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `Vec<i32>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&i32`
 --> src/main.rs:2:37
  |
2 |     v.iter().filter(|x| x % 2 == 0).collect()
  |                                     ^^^^^^^ value of type `Vec<i32>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&i32>`
  |
  = help: the trait `FromIterator<&i32>` is not implemented for `Vec<i32>`
  = help: the trait `FromIterator<T>` is implemented for `Vec<T>`
note: required by a bound in `collect`
```

Why does the above give an error, but passing it in by value does not, as shown below?

```
fn get_even_numbers(v: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    v.into_iter().filter(|x| x % 2 == 0).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<i32> = (0..10).collect();
    let even: Vec<i32> = get_even_numbers(v);
    println!("Even numbers: {:?}", even);
}
```

```
Even numbers: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

I used `.iter()` inside the function when passing in by reference and `.into_iter()` when passing in by value, not sure if these are the correct functions to use.

Comment: Iterating over a borrowed vector iterates over references to values. Handing out the actual values would require moving them from the vector, and that's only allowed if the vector itself is consumed in the process. Which is why the version with `into_iter()` works - since `into_iter()` consumes the vector, it does pass the ownership of vector's elements to the consumer of the iterator. Since `i32` is `Copy`, you can fix the borrowed version by adding a dereference, e.g. by changing `.collect()` to `.copied().collect()`.

Answer (score 7):

Use `v.iter().filter(|x| x % 2 == 0).cloned().collect()`.  That will (trivially) clone each of the `&i32` references into actual `i32` values.

Comment: You can use `copied()` instead of `cloned()` to assert (at compile time) that the clone is trivial.